# How to access an array index by its value in a Django Template?

Tags: python, arrays, django

I have an step array and a method to access in which step the process is. This method returns the process name. I need to get the position of the array where the value is equal to the step I am at.

Example:

Models

```
# models.py

steps = ['passo_open','passo_edit','passo_add_file','passo_judge']

step = process.get_current_step()

print step 
#prints 'passo_edit'
```

Template

```
# mytemplate.html

{{ step }}
# prints 'passo_edit'

{{ steps }}
# prints ['passo_open','passo_edit','passo_add_file','passo_judge']
```

What I need is to get 1 instead:

```
myStep = 1
```

I know I can get the step by index, for example:

```
{{ steps.3 }} ## prints 'passo_judge'
```

What I need is:

```
    # value = how_to_get_index(steps,step)
    # print value
    # prints 3
```

I have a bunch of links for the steps but I have to print only if it's lower than the next_step. That's why I have to get the number so I can print the links in the template until **myStep**. How can I get the index of the array by its value inside the Django Template?

Comment: It's unclear what you are really want, you have an array, and you what do actually want? Where did `next_step` come from?

Comment: myStep is what I want. I have a function which returns the step name, and other which returns all steps. I want to get the index of the array in which the element value is equal to the value I have, in this case the step. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible usind built-in Django Template features, because Django discourages adding too much logic to the templates. You could create another function that returns the current step index instead of it's value.

If you really need to do this on the template (even though it's not recommended), you could write a [Custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/) like the one below:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='cut')
def list_index_from_value(list_, value):
    return list_.index(value)
```

And on the template you could use like that:

```
{{ steps|list_index_from_value:step }}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what is `process` variable, but it seems to me that this is kind of object of some class.

You can rewrite `process.get_current_step()` to return step name and it's index

```
class Process:
    _current_step = 0
    steps = ['passo_open','passo_edit','passo_add_file','passo_judge']

    def get_current_step():
        return steps[_current_step], _current_step
```

here `.get_current_step()` will return `tuple`, where first value would be step name and second one would be current_step

If you want your variable to store only your step name then use

```
step, _ = process.get_current_step()
```

If you want to have tuple then just

```
step = process.get_current_step()
```

And then in your template you would have

```
{{ step }}  # prints 'passo_judge', 1
```

Comment: Yes, process is an object. I can't rewrite the function because it's used in other places in the code. I've thought about it, creating another method inside models.py in order to get the index of the array. I'll see what can be done. Thanks!

Comment: I believe that there should be a method that returns current step.